# Force closing of apps automatically

Tags: force-close

On my Android phone, many applications that I open closes right away, returning me to home screen.

Every time I open the application, it force closes.

Now, just recently, the browser is beginning to close, but not immediately like the apps.

I have uninstalled and re-installed apps, done virus scans, and even factory reset. Nothing has helped.

Comment: There's not enough information here. What device? What version of the OS? Are you rooted? Are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: Also, are just some of the apps crashing, or all of them? If only particular, which ones?

Comment: Ok I am really illiterate when it comes to this stuff. My phone is a huawei ascend, and I do believe it is rooted. As far as the OS or ROM I am clueless. Pretty much all of my apps are crashing most right away but like maybe 2 apps will stay open for a little while before crashing. I have removed SD card and factory reset and reinstalled apps to no prevail. And I do not have any idea how to go about the second suggestion

Answer (score 1):

First of all

- Remove the SD Card/ Make a Factory Reset (Reset Internal Storage)
- Try Installing the applications, if it ok, then scan the SD card and use.

Secondly,

- Try re-install the OS
- Flash with your stock firmware.

It will solve the issue.